# Ascii to html encoding

Tags: python, html, encoding

How I can encode a string(ascii) to html code?
For example, `string = "encoding html"`
The result should be after encoding `string_encoded = "encoding&nbsp;html"`

Comment: `string_encoded = string.replace(' ','&nbsp;')` .... Njoy

Comment: @BhargavRao the white space was an example, what about other characters like new line and others ?

Comment: That's why I voted to close. This question is way off the normal course of questions on SO. You have not tried anything. Remember this is not a site to write codes.

Comment: @BhargavRao its not a code , am just asking if there is a built-in function or a module that can encode to html , I didn't ask to write a code to me !!!

Comment: That means, It's further off-topic ...

Comment: HTML isn't an encryption charset.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use cgi.escape to replace the characters <, > and &. For most cases that will be all you need. Example:

```
>>> import cgi
>>> cgi.escape("<Foo & Bar>") 
'&alt;Foo &amp; Bar&gt;'
```

The `&nbsp;` symbol isn't really needed unless you are forcefully adding a space to the markup, which no library will naturally do for you.